# UILabel not responding to touch event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am using following code to create my view. My `UILabel` is inside a scrollview. now i want click event in `touchesBegan` method of my custom label.  but unable to get it.

```
        img1 = [[customLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,height ,280,10 )];//
        [img1 setText: [self.answer_set objectAtIndex:i]];
        [img1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [img1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:127.0f/255.0f green:165.0f/255.0f blue:234.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        img1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        img1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        img1.numberOfLines = 0;
        [img1 sizeToFit];
        img1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        img1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f] ;

        CGFloat labelHeight=[self getStringHeightforLabel:img1];
        NSLog(@"LABEL HEIGHT:: %f",labelHeight);
        //set frame after getting height
        if (labelHeight < 60.0) {
            labelHeight = 60.0;
        }

        [img1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        img1.tag = 5000;

        img1.frame=CGRectMake(-5,height,285 + 10,labelHeight + 10);
        img1.layer.cornerRadius = 5;


        /** Shadow */
        CALayer *shadowLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        shadowLayer.frame = CGRectMake(-5,height ,img1.frame.size.width,img1.frame.size.height);
        shadowLayer.cornerRadius = 10;

        shadowLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127.0f/255.0f green:165.0f/255.0f blue:234.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5;
        [img1.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        [shadowLayer addSublayer:img1.layer];

        [self.ans_labels.layer addSublayer:shadowLayer];

         height += img1.frame.size.height + 15;
```

and to get event:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

NSLog(@"worked",nil);
//[self giveAnswer:touch.view.tag];
if(touch.view.tag == 5000){
     // do here
   }
}
```

I was able to get event earlier,but not today. what i'm doing wrong ???

Comment: where you have added tapgesture for touch event on label

Comment: remove above code and paste `touchesBegan ` method and let you know that `touchesBegan ` is for view not for label.you must have to use `tapgesture` on label

Comment: I haven't used tapgesture. i want to use this method `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;`

Comment: see my updated comment

Comment: I have subclassed the `UILabel` and its inside scrollview. Can they create issue ????

Comment: this method is working fine out side of `UIScrollView`. but in side it i can't get touch event of `UILabel`. why ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I ended up with following solution :

1) I added following code to my `UIScrollView`:

```
scroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scroll.exclusiveTouch = YES;
scroll.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
scroll.delaysContentTouches = YES;
```

2) I wanted a touch event, So I added a `UIButton` over my `UILabel` of type custom,with clear background color and having same frame size as of label.

3) and last and most important thing, I must have to add `UIButton` to `UIScrollView`.

All these give me exact functionality which I wanted.

Comment: Ok nice it was great:)

Answer (score 7):

```
yourLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)];
tapGesture.delegate=self;
[yourLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


- (void)labelTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognize {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
 [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: I am creating those labels programmaticlly. Ans i have enabled userinteraction also.

Comment: yes i-droid you are correct if you diable uerineteraction also it should call the method touch began. I have update the ans. Please follow this

Comment: ok did you try this method as well -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event??